# Geometry Nodes: Mesh curve index math

Tags: geometry-nodes

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want to get:

[image]

The latter is made with scaling instances, that's not what I want.

I want to be able to reverse-delete the geometry by controlling the point indices with math nodes and such.

So, how to control the indices in order to get to the result I want?

EDIT: I also need 'smoothing' or 'easing' to the beginning and the end of each mini-line, that's a whole another challenge, perhaps.

Here are the nodes of the first example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can maybe try this:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

this is not exactly what you want - but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Seems to be very close to what I want, actually, yes. This is introducing a very nice way to use 'point' and 'instance' indices, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 3):

And here I refined [Chris' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/295033/8282) to include some easing, excellent!

One can easily change the easing in the 'Float Curve' node.

[image]

[image]

Nodes:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Alternative answer](https://twitter.com/chanfiroly/status/1669710778268524546?s=20) from Chanfiroly in Twitter, great to have alternative ways of realizing this :)

[image]